# Removing An Object From Core Mongoose Array Before Pushing New Object Into It

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a user model in which there is an array of tokens. Each token is an object having three key value pairs. I want to keep only one token object in tokens array with key **'access'='auth'** .The code I have written is not working.Every time I run the code the new token geting pushed without removing existing object with key **'access'='auth'**.Please help.

**My user object looks like this:-**

```
 {
        "_id": "5badcc621818710a2a8fcafa",
        "email": "example@gmail.com",
        "password": "example",
        "tokens": [
            {
                "_id": "5badcc661818710a2a8fcafb",
                "access": "auth",
                "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9."
            },
            {
                "_id": "5badcf6b11a6610a9d5b3f52",
                "access": "auth",
                "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9."
            },
            {
                "_id": "5badcf853776410aa7bdfaba",
                "access": "auth",
                "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9."
            }
        ]
    }
```

**I am pushing new object into tokens array when this function get called:-**

```
userSchema.methods.genAuthToken = function () {

    var token = jwt.sign(data, SECRET_KEY).toString();

    var access = 'auth';
```

> ===>this.tokens.pull( { access: 'auth' } ); //NOT WORKING

```
    this.tokens.push({ access, token });

    return this.save().then(() => token);
}
```

I want to remove all existing objects where key 'access' has value 'auth' and then push new object and then save the user object.

Answer (score 1):

Use filter instead. The below code should work:

userSchema.methods.genAuthToken = function () {

```
var token = jwt.sign(data, SECRET_KEY).toString();

var access = 'auth';
```

> this.tokens = this.tokens.filter(function (token) { return token.access !== 'auth' });

```
this.tokens.push({ access, token });

return this.save().then(() => token);
```

Filter will remove all the objects that have access equal to auth.

Comment: It is mongo array. Normal array operations will not work on it. I have already tried this.